# Installing atom-beautify on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, atom-editor

I've been trying to install atom-beautify on my Windows 10 x64 machine, but I keep getting this error :

```
npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\*****\.atom\.apm\_logs\2019-01-18T06_40_37_988Z-debug.log
```

Googling about it, I found this is an issue that has been raised but closed without much in the way of resolution : https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/2240

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Atom, and also deleting the .apm folder  and giving it another go, and then trying to install previous versions of atom-beautify using the following,

```
apm install atom-beautify@0.33.2
apm install atom-beautify@0.32.5
```

But nothing seems to work, and I get the same error with a Deprecation warning on the latter. Has anyone else encounteredd this issue, are there any known work-arounds for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround that works for now. In uninstalling from the Add and Remove service in Windows, the ".atom" folder seems to remain behind. It's in here

```
C:/Users/user_name/.atom
```

I deleted the aforementioned folder after uninstalling Atom and then reinstalled it, and now the package was installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here I followed following steps:-

step 1) File -> Exit
step 2) Open Atom again
step 3) Install Packages
step 4) All packages installed successfully

Basically just restarting my atom worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For window user, Me
I follow this step:

1. I deleted the .apm folder inside the .atom folder
2. I exit Atom and Open Atom Again
3. Installed the package and the package is installed successfully.
   Hope this step works for you

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to solve this problem is to restart the atom software or restart the pc and the try to install packages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).